# Regex: Add hyphen dash at the beginning of the line, where it does not exist hyphen dash

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

good-afternoon. I want to add hyphen (dash) at the beginning of the line, where doesn't exist hyphen dash. For example I have this text:

```
I love books.
I want some money.
I need help.
- I want to ask you something.
- I want to love you.
I need hits.
- I get done with this.
```

**The Output should be:**

```
- I love books.
- I want some money.
- I need help.
- I want to ask you something.
- I want to love you.
- I need hits.
- I get done with this.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add a hyphen dash at the beginning of the line, where doesn't exist hyphen dash.**

FIND: `^(?!-)`

REPLACE BY: `-\x20`

or

FIND: `^(?!-)(?:\r?|\r)`

REPLACE BY: `-\x20`

**If you want to add a hyphen (dash) only where there are blank lines:**

FIND: `^(?!-)\s*\r`

REPLACE BY: `-\x20`

or

FIND: `^(?!-)(?!\w+)`

REPLACE BY: `-\x20`